# Bootstrap disable hover behaviour

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

I really like the Bootstrap outline button and prefer them over the filled variant. Unfortunately, if they do get clicked or hovered over, they turn back into regular filled buttons. Is there a way to keep them outlined even when hovered over or clicked?

I tried to reset the default style on hover, but I don't think that overwrites the default hover behavior.

```
button:hover{
    @extend .btn;
    @extend .btn-outline-success;
}
```

Comment: When you say they "turn back into regular filled buttons", what do you mean? Do you mean that their hover state is filled? Because to change that, you would over-ride the built-in `:hover` to apply a `background-color`. Don't try and use `inherit` - specify the color you want and it should work. (And I'd be trying to get it right by using the Bootstrap classes before adding your own custom class like that.)

Comment: Well I've been reading the bootstrap documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#outline-buttons and it makes no mention of a way to disable the hover behaviour. I didn't want to manually fiddle with the settings, since I didn't know how many settings were changed by bootstrap or if I ever change the theme. But it turned out pretty easy. So thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres how I ended up doing it, it disables all effects (for different color variants, you will have to do them individually):

```
.btn-primary:hover,.btn-primary:focus,.btn-primary:active, 
.btn-primary:active:focus:not(:disabled):not(.disabled),
.btn:focus, .btn:active, .btn:hover{
    box-shadow: none!important;
    outline: 0;
    background-color:transparent;
    color:var(--bs-primary);
}
```